# How to center 2 divs next to each other with a specific width

Tags: css

I know this is a drawn out question but with all the examples I could find on the net for some reason I cannot replicate.

I need 2 div boxes that are 300px; wide to be next to each other and be centered in the middle.

I have the following code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center";
    }
    .box1 {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
    }
    .box2 {
        float:right;
        width:300px;
    }
</style>
```

For whatever reason I can get the boxes next to each other but it stays on the left side of the screen instead of the center. I just need them centered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: http://jsbin.com/ubanuf/12/edit (not mine)

It is cause you have `float: left`. There are several ways to do that, you can add `display: inline-block;`  or add `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.box1 {
        float:left;
        width:300px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .box2 {
        float:right;
        width:300px;
         display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS as follow

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.box1, .box2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:300px;
}
```

`inline-block` elements will be align with the text, if you set the `text-align: center` for the `container` `div`. 
you have extra (") double quote at your CSS `text-align: center";`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other way (there are plenty indeed!):

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}
.box1 {
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box2 {
    float: right;
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is redundant space between the two child DIVs if you use `inline-block`, [here](http://jsbin.com/AKoFasur/2/edit) is my solution.

```css
container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 0; // hack the space
}
.container div{
    font-size: 16px; // hack "hack the space"
}
.box1 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
}
.box2 {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you does not need to do any thing..just give box1 and box2 width in "%" or give container width in "Pixel". That will solve your problem

Like This

```
 <style>
    .container {
    width:100%; //or change it to 600px
    text-align:center";
   }
   .box1 {
    float:left;
    width:300px; //or change it to 50%
   }
   .box2 {
    float:right;
    width:300px; //or change it to 50%
   }
</style>
```

Try to keep everything in "%" or "Pixel"
Thanks